# how can I add a switch to this RLC circuit?

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-cd, circuits, qcircuit

i got this RLC circuit:

[image: circuit]

it is all set, but I need to add a switch to the node colored yellow, like this:

[image]

and this is the code I got so far:

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) to[battery1 = \SI{12}{\volt}] (0,3)
to[short, -*] (2,3);
\draw (2,3) to[short] (2,4)
to[R=\SI{100}{\ohm}] (5,4) to[short, -*] (5,3);
\draw (2,3) to[short] (2,2)
to[R=\SI{60}{\ohm}] (5,2) -* (5,3);
\draw (5,3) to[short, -*, ] (7,3)
to[american inductor = \SI{2}{\mu \henry}] (7,0);
\draw (7,3) -- (10,3)
to[capacitor = \SI{3}{m\farad}] (10,0);
\draw (0,0) to[short, -*] (7,0) to[short, -*] (10,0);
;\end{circuitikz}
```

**thanks in advance!!**

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582558/how-can-i-draw-the-switch

Comment: I think I voted for duplicate too fast --- the OP's problem is how to rotate the switch and correctly connecting the wires (they could have told that more explicitly, though...;-)). @archange answer is ok, please re-open or change the duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341651/circuitikz-draw-spdt-vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [my cute switch drawing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616212/56823), you can do something like that:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx,american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    % Switch first, as we need coordinates
    \draw node[cute spdt mid,rotate=215] (S) {};
    \node at (S-in) [above] {S};
    \node at (S-out 1) [left] {b};
    \node at (S-out 2) [above] {a};
    % Main circuit
    \draw (S-in) to[short] ++(2,0)
                 to[capacitor = \SI{3}{\milli\farad}] ++(0,-3) coordinate (R)
                 to[short, *-] (S-out 1 |- R)
                 to[short, *-] ++(-7,0)
                 to[battery1 = \SI{12}{\volt}] ++(0,3)
                 to[short, -*] ++(2,0) coordinate (L)
                 to[short] ++(0,1)
                 to[R=\SI{100}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
                 to[short, -*] ++(0,-1)
                 to[short] (S-out 2)
    % Inductor branch
          (S-out 1) to[L = \SI{2}{\micro\henry}] (S-out 1 |- R)
    % Secondary resistor branch
          (L) to[short] ++(0,-1)
              to[R=\SI{60}{\ohm}] ++(3,0)
              to[short] ++(0,1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image: circuit with switch]

Due to limitations in the switch orientation in circuitikz (normally left/right, here rotated by 215 degrees), we have to use the internal nodes (`S-*`). I also use the `(node1 |- node2)` syntax to get the intersections automatically. Feel free to ask in the comment if anything is not clear enough to you.

Comment: do you know how can i label the switch nodes? i need to label the one coming from the resistances as "a" and the other for the inductor as "b"

Comment: @ronny, just position a node near the switch `out 1` and `out 2`. I suggest to follow the first tutorial in the Ti*k*Z manual.

Comment: I’ve updated the code to use internal nodes thanks to a hint from @Rmano in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617526/56823), and also added the `a` and `b` (and `S` while at it) labels as asked (even if you’ve figured them out by yourself, which is better, that is still useful for reference).